# Jquery mobile: How to show popup only when first loading the page?

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, mobile, popup

I started developing my first mobile app using jquery mobile. 
So far it has been going nicely, but I am not able to solve a specific popup behaviour.

What I want it for a popup to show once the user loads the app. This popup should be similar to a add to home popup like you see in many apps. It is intended to point the users direction to the fixed footer with some important buttons. I managed to insert this popup and open it on page load, but there are two things I am not able to do.

1. My popup loads and disappears, which I want, and that is all OK. However, once you reload the page, or navigate to another and go back, it opens up again. This is annoying for the user. I would like it to open up only the first time you load the home page.
2. I would like to position the popup above the footer, so not over it, but above. How would I do this? Do I use x and y, and if yes how?
3. Is there a way for the overlay effect to obscure the whole page, except the footer?

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-position="fixed" data-role="header" data-theme="d">
<h1>Prva pomoć</h1>
    <button data-icon="info" data-iconpos="right"></button>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="d">
<li data-role="list-divider">Ne reagira i ne diše
</li>
<li><a href="#page2">Oživljavanje</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page3">Oživljavanje + AVD</a></li>
<li data-role="list-divider">Ne reagira, ali diše</li>
    <li><a href="#page4">Bočni položaj</a></li>
    <li data-role="list-divider">Ostalo</li>
    <li><a href="#page4">Gušenje</a></li></ul></div> 
    <div id="popspot"></div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popup" data-transition="slidedown" data-position-to="#popspot" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="e" data-history="true">
<p>U slučaju hitnoće koristi ovaj izbornik!<p></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            $(":jqmData(role='page'):last").on("pageshow", function(event) {
              $("#popup", $(this)).popup("open");
               setTimeout(function(){
      $("#popup").popup("close");
    }, 3000);
            });
        </script>
    <div data-role="footer" id="hitnizbor" data-position="fixed" class="nav-glyphish-example">
<div class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="b" data-role="navbar" data-theme="e">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#popup" data-rel="popup" id="chat" data-icon="custom">Zovi Hitnu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="email" data-icon="custom">Oživljavanje</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="skull" data-icon="custom">Osobni podaci</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Pozdrav, ako još uvijek trebaš pomoć javi mi se na privatni mail: dragan.gaic@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sessionStorage or localStorage to keep track of the information related to whether pop up is shown or not.

You code would be something as below

```
if (localStorage.popUpShown != 'true') {
        // window will position the pop up to center
        $('#popup').popup('open', {positionTo: 'window'});

        localStorage.popUpShown = 'true';
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#popup").popup("close");
        }, 3000);
    }
else{
        // Can remove this alert in development enviornment.
        alert('already shown the popup');
    }
```

you can check the <kbd>**[live fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/MyaE9/)**</kbd> here http://jsfiddle.net/mayooresan/MyaE9/

Also did some tweaking to your html. You had markup errors in your html page.

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-position="fixed" data-role="header" data-theme="d">

<h1>Prva pomoć</h1>

        <button data-icon="info" data-iconpos="right"></button>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="d">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Ne reagira i ne diše</li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Oživljavanje</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Oživljavanje + AVD</a>

            </li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Ne reagira, ali diše</li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Bočni položaj</a>

            </li>
            <li data-role="list-divider">Ostalo</li>
            <li><a href="#page4">Gušenje</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="popspot"></div>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popup" data-transition="slidedown" data-position-to="#popspot" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="e" data-history="true">
            <p>U slučaju hitnoće koristi ovaj izbornik!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" id="hitnizbor" data-position="fixed" class="nav-glyphish-example">
        <div class="nav-glyphish-example" data-grid="b" data-role="navbar" data-theme="e">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#popup" data-rel="popup" id="chat" data-icon="custom">Zovi Hitnu</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" id="email" data-icon="custom">Oživljavanje</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#" id="skull" data-icon="custom">Osobni podaci</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: I used the following code, but it does not close the popup?


 `<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        $(document).on('pageshow', function (event) {
if (sessionStorage.popUpShown != 'true') {
      
        $('#strelica').popup('open', {positionTo: '#hitnizbor'});

        sessionStorage.popUpShown = 'true';
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#strelica").popup("close");
        }, 3000);
    }
 
else{
        // Can remove this alert in development enviornment.
        alert('already shown the popup');
    }

});
               
            </script>`